# How is vertical exaggeration calculated for voxel layers in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, vertical

I am currently working with ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2. For my bachelor thesis it is my goal to visualize clouds. Therefore, I have netCDF-Files containing the cloud area fraction for each z/lat/lon grid point. The main problem I am having is the following: Instead that the z-coordinate is taken from the file, the voxel layer generates itself an automatic offset and an automatic vertical exaggeration. Unfortunately, I can't find how this vertical exaggeration is created or how I have to change it, that the layers are on the correct height (I know, that I can change the offset and the vertical exaggeration in the voxel layer menu under appearance). If I click on a created cell I do have the information regarding the depth (in meters), but it isn’t represented on this geometric height (above sea level).

Here is the structure of the netCDF-File and its parameters:

```
netcdf file:CloudsClassified.nc {
  dimensions:
    time = 1;
    longitude = 1170;
    latitude = 786;
    Height = 12;
  variables:
    float time(time=1);
      :_FillValue = -3.4028235E38f; // float
      :axis = "T";
      :calendar = "gregorian";
      :long_name = "time";
      :standard_name = "time";
      :units = "hours since 2021-01-01 12:00:00";

    float CloudClassification(time=1, Height=12, latitude=786, longitude=1170);
      :_FillValue = -3.4028235E38f; // float

    float longitude(longitude=1170);
      :_FillValue = -3.4028235E38f; // float
      :axis = "X";
      :long_name = "Longitude";
      :standard_name = "longitude";
      :units = "degrees_E";

    float latitude(latitude=786);
      :_FillValue = -3.4028235E38f; // float
      :axis = "Y";
      :long_name = "Laitude";
      :standard_name = "latitude";
      :units = "degrees_N";

    float Height(Height=12);
      :_FillValue = -3.4028235E38f; // float
      :axis = "Z";
      :positive = "down";
      :standard_name = "Height";
      :units = "meters";

  // global attributes:
  :history = "Thu Dec 09 11:04:09 2021: cdo remapbil,mygrid.desc ../laf2021010112.nc laf2021010112_latlon.nc\nProduced by fieldextra version v12.8.7 (v12.8.6) on 2021-04-02 12:38  +0:00";
  :source = "model: cosmo, production_status: research, version: not available, generating_process: unknown, product_category: determinist";
  :ConventionsURL = "http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/v1.6.0/cf-conventions.pdf";
  :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.9.5 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)";
  :institution = "MeteoSwiss";
  :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.9.5 (http://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)";
  :Conventions = "CF-1.6";
}
```

As wished some screenshots:
[image: The uploaded netCDF file is inserted in the ArcGIS, but there is an offset and an automatically generated vertical exaggeration.]

[image: The hight should be on 5000m of the top layer, but for some unknown reason it is displayed only a little bit above the ground.]

The uploaded netCDF file is inserted in the ArcGIS, but there is an offset and an automatically generated vertical exaggeration.The hight should be on 5000m of the top layer, but for some unknown reason it is displayed only a little bit above the ground. Also it's unclear to me, why the category is called depth and not hight. I didn't find any information on ArcGIS.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the output observed?

Comment: @YogeshChavan done! I hope it helps you! Thanks for every hint!